# Largest Row or Column in Matrix

Tags: java, arrays

`Given an NxM 2D array, you need to find out which row or column has largest sum (sum of its elements) overall amongst all rows and columns.

Input Format :
 Line 1 : 2 integers N and M respectively, separated by space

Line 2: Single line having N*M elements entered in row wise manner, each separated by space.

Output Format :
 If row sum is maximum then - "row" row_num max_sum
 If column sum is maximum then - "column" col_num max_sum

Note :
      If there are more than one rows/columns with maximum sum consider the 
  row/column that comes first. And if ith row and jth column has same sum (which 
  is largest), consider the ith row as answer.

My code below

```
public static void findLargest(int input[][]){
  int m=input.length;
  int n=input[0].length;
  int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
  int q = 0;
  int sum=0;
  String s = "";
 // int a[]=new int [m+n];
  //for row sum
  for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
  {
    sum=0;
    for(int j=0; j<m; j++)
    {
      sum =sum +input[i][j];

    }
    if(sum>max){
      max = sum;
      q = i;
      s = "row";
    }
    }
  // for col
  for(int i=0; i<m; i++)
  {
    sum=0;
    for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
    {
      sum=sum+input[j][i];

    }
  if(sum>max){
    max = sum;
    q = i;
    s = "column";
  } 
  }
  System.out.println(s + " "  + q + " " + max);
}
```

Comment: Seems like you're asking a homework question: have a look at [How do I ask and answer homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) first pls. Tl;dr: show your implementation and ask about the specific problem where you got stuck.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! Your question is quite unclear. Could you explain what part of your code is not working? Creating a [MCVE] would be a good start. Also, you may want to take a look at the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Hi , my code be working fine for M*M square array but it fails in case of M*N type Matrix array ??? I find myself stuck in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have almost gotten the solution, the only problem is that you are not resetting the *sum1* and *sum2* before calculating the sum of each row and column respectively. You should do it right before the second loop in each case.

Comment: I have checked for the same but it fails in case of M * N type Matrix Array , its be fine for square type Matrix Array @NiVeR

Comment: Hmm, are you sure?

Comment: yeah , I m sure.    3 4
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 10 11 12
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
 at javalangcharacter/javalangcharacter.checkkk.findLargest(checkkk.java:22)
 at javalangcharacter/javalangcharacter.checkkk.main(checkkk.java:61)         @NiVeR

Comment: Ok, you have switched n, m initially. Just change at the initialization stage n with m.

Comment: true for square matrix @ NiVeR     4 4
6 7 8 9 
6 5 7 8
 5 6 8 8 
1 2 3 4
row 0 30

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the array data as a string where the elements are separated by spaces and you have saved the dimensions N,M as integers the following code should solve your problem.

```
private int findMax(String s, int N, int M) {
    return findMaxSum(s.split(" "), N, M);
}

private int findMaxSum(String[] data, int N, int M) {
    int max = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        max = Math.max(columnSum(data, i, N, M), max);
        max = Math.max(rowSum(data, i, N, M), max);
    }

    return max;
}

private int columnSum(String[] data, int columnIndex, int N, int M) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        sum += Integer.parseInt(data[i * N + columnIndex]);
    }
    return sum;
}

private int rowSum(String[] data, int rowIndex, int N, int M) {
    int sum = 0;
    System.out.println("row");
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        sum += Integer.parseInt(data[rowIndex * N + i]);
        System.out.println(data[rowIndex * N + i]);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I code for the same and assuming N*M Matrix elements are separated by space and its output be largest sum among rows and columns and print the respective row or column.

```
enter code here


public static void findLargest(int input[][]){
  int m=input.length;
  int n=input[0].length;
  int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
  int q = 0;
  String s = "";
  for(int i=0; i<m; i++)
  {
    int sum=0;
    for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
    {
      sum =sum +input[i][j];

    }
    if(sum>max){
      max = sum;
      q = i;
      s = "row";
    }
  }
  for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
  {
   int sum=0;
    for(int j=0; j<m; j++)
    {
      sum=sum +input[j][i];

    }
  if(sum>max){
    max = sum;
    q = i;
    s = "column";
  } 
  }
  System.out.println(s + " "  + q + " " + max);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
This code will work for every case, rather it be a square matrix or not -->
( The code has been written in 

public static void rowOrColumn(int[][] input) {
        int rows = input.length;
        int columns = input[0].length;
        int largest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        int x = 0;
        int sum1 = 0;
        int sum2 = 0;
        String s = "";
        for(int i=0;i<rows;i++) {
            sum1 = 0;
            int j = 0;
            for(;j<columns;j++) {
                sum1 += input[i][j];
            }
            if(sum1>largest) {
                largest = sum1;
                x = i;
                s = "row";
            }
        }
        for(int i=0;i<columns;i++) {
            sum2 = 0;
            int j = 0;
            for(;j<rows;j++) {
                sum2 += input[j][i];
            }
            if(sum2>largest) {
                largest = sum2;
                x = i;
                s = "column";
            }
        }
    System.out.println(s + " " + x + " " + largest);
    }

    public static int[][] takeInput(){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int rows = sc.nextInt();
        int columns = sc.nextInt();
        int[][] arr = new int[rows][columns];
        for(int i=0;i<rows;i++) {
            for(int j=0;j<columns;j++) {
                arr[i][j] = sc.nextInt();
            }
        }
        return arr;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] arr = takeInput();
        rowOrColumn(arr);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# LARGEST COLUMN SUM IN A 2-D ARRAY
def lar_Col_Sum1(li):
    n = len(li) 
    m = len(li[0]) 
    max_sum = -1  
    max_sum = -1 
    for j in range(m):
        sum = 0
        for ele in li:
            sum += ele[j]
        if sum>max_sum:
            max_sum = sum
            max_index = j

    max_rindex = -1
    max_rsum = -1
    for i in range(n):
        sum = 0
        for j in range(m):
            sum += li[i][j]
        if sum > max_rsum:
            max_rsum = sum
            max_rindex = i
    if max_sum> max_rsum:
        print('column', max_index, max_sum)
    else:
        print('row', max_rindex, max_rsum)



li = [[6,9,8,5],[9,2,4,1],[8,3,9,3],[8,7,8,6]]
lar_Col_Sum1(li)
```

Comment: Code only answers are not considered good practice. Please consider [Explaining how this answers the question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers)